# cutting off meshes in the bge (bad)

Tags: game-engine

when i start my game in the bge, a plane is overlapping objects and they get closer when moving, but the part that the plane is extended to, is the part at the foremost of everything. [image: image of game while playing]

[image: image of same set while in viewport (editor)]

Answer (score 0):

[image: How to fix alpha sorting and backface culling.]

- Go to the material settings.
- Disable *Backface Culling* to see both sides of the material faces.
- Set the *Alpha Blend* option to *Alpha Clip* (recommended) or *Alpha Sort* to fix the overlapping faces.